# Testing callback passing in nodejs function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, callback, sinon

With the following example of code, I'd like to know.

```js
function testMe( input, callback ) {
  
    callback = callback || function () {};  /* 1 */
  
    // process input ...
    process( input, function (err, result ) { 
        if( err ) {
            return callback( new Error('fail processing input') ); /* 2 */
        }

        return callback( null, result ); /* 3 */
    });
}
```

1. How can I test above 3 positions of `callback` with SinonJS?
2. Is it a good practice that I reset callback at position 1?

Appreciate your comments.

Comment: In this version of your sample, `testMe` is entirely useless beyond `process` itself and you may as well just call `process` directly and delete `testMe` entirely. If you were doing some pre-processing of `input` or post-processing of `output` than the existence of `testMe` would be justified.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice that I reset callback at position 1?

In your case, no, it is an anti-pattern. Looking at the semantics of your `testMe` function, it is designed to take input and call back with either the output or an error. Making the callback optional will just mask the error, delaying bug detection and making debugging that much more of a mystery to solve. If the caller does not need the output at all, why bother calling the function in the first place? Defaulting the callback function does not actually help as good program flow and semantics cannot be done with "fire and forget"/"side effects only" behavior that you get with no callback.

*Aside*: your sample does not actually have any asynchronous behavior. If your real code is actually like this, it can just return synchronously and throw errors synchronously - a callback is not necessary or correct in that case. But I suspect you have "simplified" your example but your real code is in fact asynchronous.

Comment: thanks for giving me some points. I've just edited the example code.